# reorganize layout on orientation change in titanium

Tags: appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

I have a layout that has sum specifications when it is in portrait. But when I change the screen orientation the layout needs to reorganize to fit the entire screen. The problem is that the layout keeps he's dimensions. So if the layout starts portrait the I change to landscape the layout keeps the portrait configuration. How can I make my layout so it auto reorganizes on screen orientation changes?

How I create my views:

```
var deviceHeight = Ti.Platform.displayCaps.platformHeight,
    deviceWidth = Ti.Platform.displayCaps.platformWidth,
    platform = Ti.Platform.osname;

    if (platform == 'android') {
        deviceHeight = Math.round(Ti.Platform.displayCaps.platformHeight / Ti.Platform.displayCaps.logicalDensityFactor);
        deviceWidth = Math.round(Ti.Platform.displayCaps.platformWidth / Ti.Platform.displayCaps.logicalDensityFactor);
    }

var View = Ti.UI.createView({
    height : deviceHeight,
    width : deviceWidth,
    backgroundColor : 'white',
    layout : 'vertical'
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Very important: Don't specify width in points/pixels, but in percentages. Or use relative width. For example, if you want a view that is full width, minus 10 left and 10 right, specify that:

```
Ti.UI.createView(){
    left: 10,
    right: 10
}
```

Treat Apps different as websites! Make everything relative. There are so many resolutions it is impossible to make a layout PER resolution. Make a single solution for mobile, and possible re-arrange some stuff for tablets.

If you really want to redraw manually, use this event and redefine all your views after again:

```
Ti.Gesture.addEventListener('orientationchange',function(e) {
});
```

For this to work, you need to keep a reference to all your views and adjust where you like.

Comment: you really don't want to custom do that with width and height of the device. Then you will have to redraw every element manually. See my edit